# Rails form with nested attributes. text_field not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, nested-form-for

Issue: I have a nested fields_for text_field not appearing, I am not sure what I have been done wrong.

Goal: While creating a record, iterate through a model with preset variables, and save a file (testing with text_field) to a join table which saves both the preset variables and the forms record ID

Models:

```
class PrintLocation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shop_products, through: :shop_product_print_files
  has_many :shop_product_print_files
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_product_print_files
end

class ShopProductPrintFile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop_products
  belongs_to :print_locations
end

class ShopProduct < ApplicationRecord
    ...
  has_many :shop_product_print_files
  has_many :print_locations, through: :shop_product_print_files
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :print_locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_product_print_files
    ...
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @shop_product do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :product_id, @products, :id, :sku %>
   <% PrintLocation.all.each do |print_location| %>
     <%= print_location.title %>
        <%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |a| %>
           <%= a.text_field :print_file %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

With this, the text_field doesn't appear but the `print_location.title`'s do appear.  There are no errors with this.

While saving the `@shop_product`, I want to be able to iterate through the possible `print_location` variables, which are defined, and then for each possible `print_location`, to then be able to upload a file (text_field for testing), and then save that to the ShopProductPrintFile model which has `shop_product_id` and `print_location_id` and `print_file` attributes.

Is there something I am misunderstanding for how to use `fields_for`?

Shop Product Controller:

Create:

```
@shop_product = ShopProduct.new(shop_product_params)
shop = Shop.find(params["shop_product"]["shop_id"])
product = Product.find(params["shop_product"]["product_id"])    @shop_product.product_id = product.id
@shop_product.shop_id = shop.id
respond_to do |format|
   if @shop_product.save!
...
```

Update:

```
@shop_product = ShopProduct.find_by(store_variant_id: params["shop_product"]["store_variant_id"])
@product = Product.find(params["shop_product"]["product_id"])
```

Strong Params:

```
def shop_product_params
   params.require(:shop_product).permit(:product_id, :store_product_id, :shop_id, :store_variant_id, :sync, :shop_product_print_file_attributes[:id, :print_files, :print_location_ids => [], :shop_product_ids => []], {print_location_ids: []})
end
```

**UPDATE 2:**

**Update and Create Method:**

@shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build

**form:**

```
<% PrintLocation.all.each do |print_location| %>
  <%= print_location.title %>
    <%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files_attributes do |a| %>
       <%= a.text_field :print_file %>
       <%= a.hidden_field :print_location_id, value: print_location.id %>
       <%= a.hidden_field :shop_product_id, value: shop_product.id %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**params:**

```
def shop_product_params
   params.require(:shop_product).permit(:shop_product_print_files_attributes => [:ids => [], :print_files => [], :print_location_ids => [], :shop_product_ids => []])
end
```

**error:**
    `Shop product print files shop products must exist`
    `Shop product print files print locations must exist`

params that pass:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"u/c103465uNCjF/trYrMleqxJ8b9wyLbU/vjPK4llYtCg/ODj92q5MN24==", "shop_product"=>{"sync"=>"1", "product_id"=>"3", "shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"6", "shop_product_id"=>"42"}, "store_product_id"=>"191234345", "store_variant_id"=>"15341234273", "id"=>"42"}, "commit"=>"Sync", "id"=>"42"}
```

The models haven't changed.

Print file in params still blank?

### UPDATE 3:

**using this form: thanks to @arieljuod **

```
<%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.object.print_location.title # get the print location from the association %> 
    <%= ff.hidden_field :print_location_id # save the print_location_id as a hidden field %>
    <%= ff.file_field :print_file # file input %>
  <% end %>
```

**with this in the new and method housing the view:**

```
@shop_product = ShopProduct.new
PrintLocation.all.each{|p| @shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build(print_location: p)}
```

works on create.

Issue still arises due to not knowing the ID of the ShopProduct until the page loads due to API and there is a possibility of being multiple IDs on one page.

**I use:**

```
<% if @shop_products.find_by(store_variant_id: variant.id)  %>
<% shop_product = @shop_products.find_by(store_variant_id: variant.id)  %>
   <%= form_for shop_product do |f| %>
   ...
```

Which, `variant` comes from a loop defined by an API:

```
<% @in_store_variants.each do |variant| %>
```

Now when using `shop_products` (from when shop_product already exists from finding by the `variant.id`), the fields_for won't appear.  Assuming this is because no records exist in relation.  Only if a shop_product.shop_product_print_files exist, will they appear.

The only work around, at this time to my knowledge, is to save all print_locations but use a boolean for which are actually active, or search for which print_locations have an ID attached.  But i would rather not do it that way and just save which print_locations are chosen on create (chosen by uploading a `print_file`).

To "fix" this issue, I:

1. added `accepts_nested_attributes_for reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['print_file'].blank? }` which doesn't save ShopProductPrintFile's unless the print_file field is submitted with something...
2. use this form (2 forms depending on if exists or not)

   ```
   <% if @shop_products.find_by(store_variant_id: variant.id)  %>
      <%= form_for shop_product do |f| %>
      <% PrintLocation.all.each{|p| shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build(print_location: p)} %>
      <%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |ff| %>
          <%= ff.object.print_location.title %>
         <%= ff.hidden_field :print_location_id %>
           <%= ff.text_field :print_file %>
      <% end %>
     <%= f.submit "Sync" %>
   <% end %>
   <% else %>
      <%= form_for @shop_product do |f| %>
      <% PrintLocation.all.each{|p| @shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build(print_location: p)} %>
      <%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |ff| %>
          <%= ff.object.print_location.title %>
          <%= ff.hidden_field :print_location_id %>
          <%= ff.text_field :print_file %>
      <% end %>
       ...
   ```

The issue with 2 is i have have PrintLocation 1,2,3 associated, it will show 9 fields, the 1,2,3 ready for update, and the 6 ready for create.

is it possible to call the `PrintLocation.all.each{|p| @shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build(print_location: p)}` on already created ShopProducts's for where a shop_product_print_file doesn't exist in relation to the possible print location.

So for example...
Created ShopProduct with print location, 1,2,3 (out of 6 possible)

Now, shop_product_print_location where print_location exists will show for updating in the form, so thats 1,2, and 3.  How can I have it so the other 3 that weren't created now show to update the ShopProduct and create new ShopProductPrintFile's? so it is possible to update the ShopProduct to have more print_locations to the shop_product_print_file model.

Comment: Nice, maybe try to add "_attributes" like so `f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files_attributes`, but I'm not sure

Comment: you're godly, however, I still have issues with the `print_file` param not passing.  It goes through blank as `"shop_product_print_file_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"6", "shop_product_id"=>"42"}` and in my strong params I have ` :shop_product_print_file_attributes [ :print_files, :shop_product_ids, :print_location_ids ]` but receiving error: too many arguments

Comment: I had this problem also, but in my case it was not nested. So I think it's because print_location_ids and shop_product_ids are arrays. So, in the strong params would be something like `product_ids:[] and shop_product_ids:[]`

I don't know about this error though,  maybe is missing the arrow ? :shop_product_print_file_attributes => [ ... ]

I hope it works ...

Comment: Also... check in the console if says something like "unpermited parameters" when you submit the form, sometimes it happens..

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant controller code?

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes ended up being becauseof my strong_params but still haven't issues.. I updated my post above at the bottom if you can have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell rails which PrintLocation to use on each iteration since your object does not have any

```
<%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files, print_location do |a| %>
```

I'm not really sure if that's what you want, but the field will appear.

EDIT: so, I think you need something like this:

On the controller

```
@shop_product = something_to_get_the_product
PrintLocation.all.each{|p| @shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build(print_location: p)}
```

I prefer to do this here, I don't like that logic on the view

Now you have all the possible print location prebuilt on the shop product object

On the form

```
# note here the multipart option to allow files
<%= form_for @shop_product, multipart: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :product_id, @products, :id, :sku %>

  <%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.object.print_location.title # get the print location from the association %> 
    <%= ff.hidden_field :print_location_id # save the print_location_id as a hidden field %>
    <%= ff.file_field :print_file # file input %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hm maybe ill try that but i made an update at the bottom of the post

Comment: Using that makes the page not load with: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `print_file' for #<PrintLocation:0x000055ace1e55e50>):` .. the goal is to save to he `shop_products_print_file` model based on each possible `print_location`

Comment: Any ideas? . . . . . . . . . .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. You want a form to display all possible print locations with a field to add a file on each of those print locations? Or a selector of the avialable print locations to upload a file? I don't really get it

Comment: Yes (to the first 1)!, so i seeded 6 possible PrintLocations into PrintLocation.  This model database will never be added to, it has `title` and `cost`.  I then have a ShopProductPrintFile model that has print_location_id, shop_product_id, print_file... In the form while creating a ShopProduct, I want to display each possible print_location, and have a print_file field to each print_location.  For now, I am using text_field for print_location for testing.  Then on submit, it will save a ShopProduct and ShopProductPrintFile(s)

Comment: thanks will test very soon and let you know...         appreciate it :)

Comment: Okay thank u much but now... so I have this working for creating ShopProducts but having some minor issues when updating mostly.  I made an update.  If anything isn't explained enough let me kno

Comment: On the `each` loop you could call build only `if @shop_product.shop_product_print_files.where(print_location: p).empty?` so it does not add an empty object if it already exists

Comment: `                      <% PrintLocation.all.each{|p| shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build(print_location: p) if shop_product.shop_product_print_files.where(print_location: p).empty? } %>` worked...thanks.I'm doing this all from the view,,, which is a whole other issues and topic

Answer (score 1):

> I have a nested fields_for text_field not appearing, I am not sure
>   what I have been done wrong.

You should add this line in your create action

```
@shop_product = ShopProduct.new(shop_product_params)
@shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build #this one
```

Also change `shop_product_print_file_attributes` to `shop_product_print_files_attributes` to avoid any further errors.

Comment: Thanks... `@shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build` should go in both update and create? (users can update)

Comment: I updated my OP with new form, params, and new error i am receiving.

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.4.5 btw if that helps... Rails 5.2.2

Comment: So doing this: `@shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build(shop_product_id: @shop_product.id, print_location_id: params["shop_product"]["shop_product_print_files_attributes"]["print_location_id"])` in the update works. but the `print_file` still appears blank on the form submit... Also having issues on Creating a `ShopProduct` because in order to Save to the `ShopProductPrintFile `mode, I need a ShopProduct and it's not yet created so the `@shop_product` in the create method doesn't pass through?

Comment: I also changed both of the `belongs_to` in the ShopProductPrintFile model to singular instead of plural

Comment: Okay so it looks like just removing the shop_product_id in the build fixes it for the create... testing more